# nvm cannot find "old installation path"

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

*Using Windows 10.*

I had installed `nvm`, `npm` and `ng` to a specific location. Not the default one.
I have uninstalled everything as I want to place them in a different location now.
I have `nvm` re-installed in a new location.

But when I run `nvm install lts`.
I get:

> ERROR open [old-path-where-I-had-previously-installed-nvm]\settings.txt:
> The system cannot find the path specified.

I searched the Internet for this, but what I find is that many users get this error message because their username have space or special characters. I'm not in this case at all, my user name is one word without special characters, and anyway, I didn't install NVM in a "User" folder. Installation path also doesn't contain any space or special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. But I'm not sure why, here are two things I did:

- Removed the old NPM path form "Path" Environment Variables. (I hardly see how this is related.)
- Closed and re-opened my Command Prompt windows. (But I though I had already done it...)